# How understand, what link from webview is YouTube link, to open it in YouTube app?lication

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview, youtube

I want, when user click on web view link,it's open YouTube app. How i can parse this link,i.e what algorithm should i use,to know,whether it link on youtube video (exact video, not channel or simple YouTube site). Because you can have,for example youtube.com,or youtu.be,so it not so obvious solution of this problem. Probably i should use regex,but i am not sure, what it right way. May be somebody decompile youtube app and asee sources of this app to know,how it understand,what it correct youtube video link. Thanks everybody for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about Deeplinks. They are declared on your apps Manifest and they can intercept any kind of links, hosts or URL schemas.

```
<intent-filter>
      ...
      <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.youtube.com" />
      <data android:scheme="app" android:host="open.my.app" />
</intent-filter>
```

> [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

If you need to intercept links in your WebView then you can add some logic in your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    if(url.equals("www.youtube.com/xxxx")) {
        launchYoutubeApp(url) ;
        return true;
    }
    
    if(uri.getHost().contains("youtube")) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    //add here any condition you need in order of preference
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I mean how parse ready link from webviewClient from method ShouldOverrideOrLoading,but not open youtube links. If i will know,what it's exact YouTube video link,i want to open it in YouTube application, but how to know it?

Comment: But link can be referenced on channeler simple on YouTube.com,but not on YouTube video. If i will have redirection to YouTube,whether uri will contains YouTube.com as host?